# What's the meaning of a note before the time signature?

Tags: notation, time-signatures, anacrusis

I'm working on a project using music sheets, but I don't understand music theory or notation.

The sheet I'm studying is *The Four Seasons*. From what I gather the sheet was written with the *MuseScore* software (the accompanying MIDI has the name of the music and author at the meta event 09 and 10).

Before the time signature for the piece there's a eighth note with the *fortissimo* mark.

What is the meaning of this note?

[image: staff with (in order from left to right): clef, key signature, eighth note with fortissimo mark (circled in red), barline, time signature, beamed eighth notes, ...]

Comment: looks like a pickup to me.  Probably a stylistic choice to keep the ledger looking artful.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's an engraving mistake.  The time signature should come straight after the key signature, before the first note.

Here's the opening of the Ricordi edition, from IMSLP.   The f indication is in brackets, this indicates that's it's an editorial addition, not in the original manuscript.

http://imslp.eu/Files/imglnks/euimg/f/f2/IMSLP386586-PMLP126432-Vivaldi__Antonio-Opere_Ricordi_F_I_No_22_scan.pdf

[image]

Comment: This does NOT have to be a mistake. It is most likely an artistic choice. Time signatures can occur whenever in a score. There are many songs that shift between 6/8 and 3/4 without re-declaring their key. Generally speaking, the first time signature is before the the first note, but in this case it is likely indicating that it is the directors choice how fast to take it, especially with the fortissimo. Without a time signature, the eighth note has no assigned length, and can therefore be taken at any tempo or length. Although, that is all theoretical and not necessarily relevant to that song.

Comment: @EvSunWoodard - you mixed up time and key sigs. Not many songs shift between 3/4 and 6/8, as the feel is quite different, and the time sig needs to be there. How does fortissimo affect timing? It's usually bpm ( or 'allegro' here) that dictates speed and tempo. The time sig is a relative thing. This comment is confusing.

Comment: Sorry, EvSunWoodard, you're way out here!  This is a simple engraving error.  End of.  Really.

Comment: @Tim I'm not saying that this cannot be an engraving error, but I am saying that the composer is a liberty to do basically whatever s/he wants. Many songs change time signature, search songs by Hazo, specifically Sevens, which purposely changes between 7/8 and 3/8 for the change in feel. While the fortissimo doesn't change the timing, without a time signature the director is a liberty to hold the note as long as s/he wants to. So, if you want to make a grand entrance, act as if that eight is a whole note, because it makes no difference without signature. Otherwise, make it short and sweet.

Comment: @EvSunWoodard - in that case, put a fermata over the note. Take a thousand mainstream songs, and I doubt if more than a dozen will have timing changes. Take a load of jazz tunes, you'll find a lot.

Comment: @Tim - I am not advocating for this to be standard practice. Yes, putting a fermata would achieve making it a long note, but it takes away the option. As written, it is optional, the note has NO value, which means the director can choose whatever value they want. A fermata must be held. This is all theoretical, and it is unlikely that this was the composers intent, but it was worth noting that it didn't HAVE to be wrong. Also, even Mozart changed time signatures. Sure you won't find it in pop music, but many classical and neoclassical songs do this. It is relatively standard practice.

Comment: @Tim Even the Beatles used changing meter, in "Here Comes the Sun" they use 11/8, 4/4, 7/8

Comment: @EvSunWoodard - yes, just trawled through over 140 Beatles songs, 7 of which had time sig changes. Hardly commonplace! I guess what I'm saying is that it could have been written in a much more succinct way, rather than that which the composer used (if indeed that's the case!) Usually composers have a shrewd idea of what they want their works to sound like, without giving as much licence as you think this allows. No, it doesn;t HAVE to be wrong, but I bet it is!

Comment: @Tim - It probably is wrong, I agree. But the OP asked what the purpose of the note was. This answer was specific to the piece, and explained that the version was misprinted. I was attempting to explain that while this version may be a misprint, there are other reasons that something like this could happen and the connotations of similar marking.

Answer (score 2):

It must be an anacrucis, but generally, the time signature is found *before* the note/s rather than *after* it. When there is an anacrucis, the last bar usually has enough beats so that the two add up to a full bar. Maybe this way, the package has decided that the last bar will be a full four beats. The 'ff' mark will apply to the next part too, not just the anacrucis.

Comment: I think the concept of the anacrusis length being subtracted from the final bar is more of an older concept that doesn't apply so much today, or at least outside of the Classical tradition.  Form is much more loose now.  Regarding the placement of the time signature, is it possible that this is not the beginning of the piece and that we are transitioning from another time signature?  That's the only reason I can think of why it would be written this way.

Comment: Also, for @Jmarkim, this is commonly referred to as a Pickup outside of the academic community.

Comment: @Basstickler - doubtful that the time sig before would be 1/8 !  Pickup not to be confused with that found on electric guitars... There's not a lot wrong with anacrucis - literally 'before the downbeat'.

Comment: I'm thinking that this would be the start of a new section and the previous section could have been in any other time signature. I still wouldn't notate that this way but it's the only thing I can think of to justify it.  The reason I mention Pickup, which is indeed than a pickup on an electric instrument, is that I literally have only ever heard the term anacrusis used in an academic setting (and here on SE), to the point that it's become dorky trivia for me with friends that also have a degree.  This may also be a cultural difference since I'm in America and you're in England.

Comment: Look folks - we know what piece it is.  It's a music engraving error.  End of.